# Linkers and loaders : static variables

Tags: c++, c, makefile, compiler-construction, loader

Can someone please explain this part by Levine from Linker and Loaders, page 131?

> the trickiest part of the symbol information is the location information. The location of a static variable doesn't change, but a local variable within a routine may be static, on the stack, in a register, or in optimized code, moved from place to place in different parts of the routine…

Does it mean that a static local variable changes its location in memory depending on the calls of the function it belongs to?

Comment: A `static` variable, in either a function, statement block, or globally, shouldn't change it's address.  Variables that are not static may change their addresses or may be stored in registers.  Common conception is to place all the static variables in the same region in memory (since they all have the same life-time).

Comment: The quote is saying that the location of **local** variables is at the whim or mercy of the compiler.  As the quote says, a local variable can be in a processor's register, on a stack, removed from the code (via optimization) or otherwise.

Comment: For example, I could have a local variable placed into Register 0.  A function is called with the variable.  The function can then copy the variable to Register 1, do some processing, then copy back to Register 0 before returning.  Compilers can also use push and pop instructions for saving registers before destroying their contents.

Comment: does it mean that a static locale variable doesn't change its location, if the function it belongs to is called elsewhere the variable is copied in the new stack adress, and after the execution copied back in the old location ?

Comment: @camelkos. No. The address of a static variable does not change, as the book says. There's no need to move variables to the stack in order to use them. It's possible for a static variable to have limited scope, (i.e. be a "local" variables), but it's still a static variable and it's placed in the data section along with other static variables.

Comment: You have to distinguish how a variable is addressed in a compiler (at compile time) vs. how it is addressed in the binary (at runtime). In the compiler, it's addressed by its name. I.e. defining a `static` variable inside a function means the compiler will deny to access it from the outside of function by its name. (That belongs to the topic of scopes.) Nevertheless, the life-time of a static variable is (at latest) from its first access until end of application. At runtime... (see above).

Answer (score 1):

No, even a "static local variable" is a static variable. It does not change its location during the runtime of the program.

The "locality" of such a variable just limits its visibility. The compiler allows to reference it only inside its local scope.

However, you could return its address to other scopes and access it by this.